# ¿Cómo hago para que dos vectores sean iguales?

Tags: java, array, netbeans, bucle-for, bucles

Buenos días tengo un problema con un código y es que 1: tengo una arraylist donde un dato guarda datos de vector de "ingredientes" y lo que necesito es imprimir los vectores u "ingredientes" que tengan un ingrediente particular ¿cómo le hago? este más o menor es mi código:

```
public class Cocina {
public int n;
private Scanner sc;
private Receta receta;   //Receta receta = new Receta();
ArrayList<Receta> recetario = new ArrayList<>();

public Cocina() {
    sc = new Scanner(System.in);
}


 private void anadirReceta() {
    System.out.println("Agrege la receta separados por (&)");
    String texto = sc.nextLine();
    String[] dato = texto.split("&");
    String nombre = dato[0];
    int timePreparation = Integer.parseInt(dato[1]);
    String tipo = dato[2];
    System.out.println("Cantos ingredientes va a agregar");
    n = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
    String [] ingredientesApoyo = new String [n];
    System.out.println("Ingrese los ingredientes separados por (&)");
    String [] texto2 = sc.nextLine().split("&");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        ingredientesApoyo[i] = texto2[i];
    }
    Receta receta = new Receta(nombre, timePreparation, tipo , true); 
    receta.setIngredientes(ingredientesApoyo); 
    recetario.add(receta);
    System.out.println(recetario);
}



private void consultarRecetaParticular() {
    for (int i = 0; i < recetario.size(); i++) {
        if ((recetario.get(i).getIngredientes()) == (recetario.get(i).getIngredientes()))  {
            System.out.println(recetario.get(i));
        }
    }

}

 class Receta {
public int n;
private Cocina cocina;
private String nombre;
private String ingredientes[]; 
private int tiempoDePreparacion;
private String tipo;
private boolean estado;

public Receta(String nombre, int tiempoDePreparacion, String tipo, boolean 
 estado) {  
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.tiempoDePreparacion = tiempoDePreparacion;
    this.tipo = tipo;
    this.estado = estado;
}


public String[] getIngredientes() {
    return ingredientes;
}

public void setIngredientes(String[] ingredientes) {
    this.ingredientes = ingredientes;
}
```

Lo necesito guardar consultarRecetaParticular eso fue lo que se ocurrió alguna ayuda plss

Ejemplo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui entonces deberia retornar el 4 porque es son ingredientes en particulares

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí no debería retornar nada ya que los ingredientes no son iguales

Comment: No puedes comprobar que dos objetos son iguales de manera sencilla o con un simple metodo, ya que si no estoy mal tu no deseas comparar si el `objeto` es el mismo ni tampoco si tienen la misma instancia, o hacen parte de la misma clase, en su lugar creo que quieres comparar es si las propiedades de uno son exactamente las mismas que las del otro, pero claro... creo que no hay un metodo prefabricado que haga esto en java.

Comment: mas o menos necesito determinar si los vectores ingredientes sean iguales como hago?

Comment: Podrias tambien anadir el metodo `setIngredientes`? es que hay algo que no me termina de cuadrar.

Comment: listo ya coloque

Comment: necesitas encontrar aquellas recetas con los exactos mismos ingredientes?
Si es asi yo miraria API Stream, te simplificaria bastante, otra sugerencia modula mas los metodos y si te sirve usa papel edit: tenes que comparar los elementos del array

Comment: ¿Podrías adjuntar tus ejemplos como texto? Para mejor legibilidad. Además, ¿los vectores son "ingredientes" o "recetas"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

veo algun tipo de estructura que puede ayudarte un poco, a ver partamos de la clase principal desde un inicio, supongamos que tu la tienes estructurada de esta manera:

```
public class TuClase{

    private static Cocina cocina;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        TuClase.cocina = new Cocina();
    }

}
```

La cocina por supuesto tiene un `recetario` el cual es un `ArrayList` que almacena recetas, por ende sabemos que cada elemento contendra una propiedad *ingredientes*

Entonces ya sabemos que debemos comparar, ahora, ten en cuenta que cuando comparamos un `String` con otro no podemos compararlos de manera normal. debes hacerlo con el metodo `equals` de esta manera:

```
String str1 = "abc";
String str2 = "abc";

str1.equals(str2);   //true
```

Si no lo haces con `equals` el resultado va a ser `false` independientemente de si las cadenas son iguales, esto es debido a que al usar `==` estas comparando si las instancias son exactamente las mismas.

entonces yo lo que haria seria crear un pequeño metodo que me permita comparar una receta con otra, y usarlo de esta manera:

```
public class TuClase{

    private static Cocina cocina;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        TuClase.cocina = new Cocina();
    }

    public static boolean compararReceta(int indiceReceta1, int indiceReceta2){
        final String[] rec1 = TuClase.cocina.recetario.get(indiceReceta1).getIngredientes();
        final String[] rec2 = TuClase.cocina.recetario.get(indiceReceta2).getIngredientes();

        for(int i = 0; i < rec1.length; i++){
           if(!rec1[i].equals(rec2[i])) return false; 
        }
       
        return true;
    }

}
```

Entonces mediante el metodo `compararReceta` podras comparar 2 recetas que esten en el listado de recetas despues de que hayas ejecutado por supuesto sus correspondientes metodos que seteen toda la informacion necesaria.

Realmente lo unico que hice aqui:

```
final String[] rec1 = TuClase.cocina.recetario.get(indiceReceta1).getIngredientes();
final String[] rec2 = TuClase.cocina.recetario.get(indiceReceta2).getIngredientes();

for(int i = 0; i < rec1.length; i++){
    if(!rec1[i].equals(rec2[i])) return false; 
}

return true;
```

Fue extraer los ingredientes de cada uno y compararlos mediante un ciclo, para ver si ambos son exactamente iguales, si alguno difiere se retorna directamente `false` y se sale del ciclo, de lo contrario se retorna `true`.

Comment: Por cierto, el metodo esta en la clase principal, pero si quieres puedes moverlo de clase haciendole sus respectivas adaptaciones, quiza quede mejor si lo pones en una clase relacionada y no en la principal, asi no contaminas la clase principal, de todas maneras, ese es solo un ejemplo para comparar los `ingredientes` de una receta con los ingredientes de otra. para los demas casos deberas aplicar algo parecido. solo habria que adaptarlo.